# How to tag sub-entity in an intent using IBM Watson？

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

An answer provide by @Simon O'Doherty in a [post：How to capture the multiple values of one entity in IBM watson assistant after asking slot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50072434/how-to-capture-the-multiple-values-of-one-entity-in-ibm-watson-assistant-after-a)
 said that we can tag entity in an intent, however, in my watson, I do not see this function. Is it be deleted？or it's a version-limited function？
If not, do anyone know how to open the function？

My waston do not show any tag option when I try to edit an intent：
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this, too, for my German language. The support for tagging contextual entities is coming slowly to non-English languages. There is an [IBM Watson Assistant doc page showing features and supported languages](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-language-support). Japanese and German are not supported (yet?) for the tagging you asked for.